# Cloud templates do not install in VS2012 when installing Azure SDK 1.8

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

I have Windows 8 and a clean install of Visual Studio 2012 with no previous versions. After installing the Azure SDK 1.8 the templates are not installed for .Net 4 or 4.5 framework.
How do we install the templates for the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio which can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448

But I suggest you try the full install via the WPI (this installs all required components): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254364&clcid=0x409

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Hope someone can see this and help.